debian sddm window manager: set focus-mode to either sloppy or mouse: no effect
On debian version 12.8 fully upgraded, sddm window manager.  Using either gsetting or dconf-editor, I can set and verify org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences focus-mode to either sloppy or mouse but neither takes effect: still have to click in window to raise focus.
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences focus-mode sloppy
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences focus-mode
'sloppy'


